# Null-safe valueOf method

Tags: java

I need to convert several String values to Integer,Boolean, etc., however since the input values may be null I can't use the `Integer.valueOf()` method for example. If the input is null I need the output object to be null as well, so I can't use [apache commons NumberUtils.toInt()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toInt%28java.lang.String%29). Is there an existing implementation or a better solution than just writing a utility method for each type(Integer, Boolean etc.)?

Edit: adding code sample

`String maxAgeStr = settings.get("maxAge"); //settings is a map, which may or 
                                            //may not contain maxAge
constraints.setMaxAge(Integer.valueOf(maxAgeStr)); // need null safety here
String enableActionStr = settings.get("enableAction");
constraints.setEnableAction(Boolean.valueOf(enableActionStr)); // need null safety here`

Comment: why would you need to write for each type? if (input==null) return null; else NumberUtils.toInt(). What don't i understand?

Comment: just wondered if there is an existing library function that already does that, prefer it to writing small utility functions myself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `commons-lang` [NumberUtils.createInteger()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#createInteger%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
NumberUtils.createInteger(null); // null
NumberUtils.createInteger("5"); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks, missed it when I was looking at the class. And for Boolean it's a different method name for some reason, BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject()

Answer (score 2):

Your `settings` object should support getter methods with different return types, for example:

```
public String getString(String name);

public int getInt(String name);

public boolean getBoolean(String name);
```

Also for simplicity you can provide a generic `get()`:

```
public <T> T get(String name);
```

This way you can do the conversion in one place (in the settings), and all the code that reads and uses the settings will remain type-safe and free of a bunch of conversions. Also this is the place where you can introduce default values, in one central place.

If you don't have many settings, best would be to add direct getter methods for each of them, for example:

```
public int getMaxAge();

public boolean isEnableAction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Touches Java 8:

```
Optional<String> maxAgeStr = Optional.ofNullable(settings.get("maxAge"));
maxAgeStr.ifPresent((str) -> { constraints.setMaxAge(Integer.valueOf(str)); });

Optional<String> enableActionStr = Optional.ofNullable(settings.get("enableAction"));
constraints.setEnableAction(Boolean.valueOf(enableActionStr.orElse(false))); 

Optional<String> enableActionStr = Optional.ofNullable(settings.get("enableAction"));
constraints.setEnableAction(Boolean.valueOf(enableActionStr.orElseGet(() -> i%2 == 0)));
```

Comment: I admit, Java 8 has started to scare me :) I really don't want to see this in the hands of almost-qualified developers.

Comment: Interesting, don't have Java 8 here yet, looks like an entirely different way of thinking -not really sure yet if I like it or not. Basically agree with eis

Comment: @eis The context matters: but basically a `get` that might return null is as of Java 8 becoming bad style. Maybe not if there would have been an `?:` orElse operator. (BTW really scary is JavaScript, see the internals of jQuery. Using returnal of undefined and such niceties.)